# MySQL based variable coming up as NULL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is in a php file I am building. I am building a dynamic form that will show  product names and other information in HTML divs. Now, I am coming to a problem, which I think is probably something relatively simple. I was originally trying to `echo $name;` but it was coming up empty, so I put in a test echo to see if perhaps it was echoing to a different place than I had expected, but nope, the test came right up. So, I did a `var_dump($name);` and it came up as NULL. I define it in the line before I echo it, so why is it coming up as NULL?

```
<?php
$productquery = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE PID="$productID"');
$productrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productquery);
//$dbIDlogin = $row5['ID'];         
?>

<?php 
$name = $productrow['Productname'];
echo var_dump($name);
echo "<br>Why?";
?>
```

Update:

vardump($productrow['Productname']) is null.

`vardump`ing `$productquery` gives this:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(18) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

2nd UPDATE:

Apparently $productID was NULL. So I'm trying to set it to 4. I now have this, and it still doesn't works. I've tried surrounding the 4 in quotes, single and double, so that isn't the problem. But it still says it is null the line after I define it.

```
$productID=4;
$productquery = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE PID="$productID"');
$productrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productquery);
```

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing all the other variables as well. And enable error reporting.

Comment: Could you try a `var_dump($productrow)` to see what's in there?

Answer (score 1):

$productrow['Productname'] is null.

Figure out what your query is actually returning with a vardump/print_r statement for $productrow

Answer (score 1):

Does $productID contain a valid number?

You'll want to iterate through the results! You're assuming that there is only 1 result, and that it doesn't need to be iterated.

Also, try displaying the number of rows found by the query:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($productquery);
```

Comment: $productID does contain a valid number.

Be careful with that deprecated code there. I'm testing now.

Comment: Okay, apparently I was wrong... it was not a valid number. I'm not sure why, I have it defined a couple lines before this...

Answer (score 0):

It appears the main problem was my use of single quotes:

```
'SELECT * FROM products WHERE PID="$productID"'
```

Rather than double quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM products WHERE PID=$productID"
```